# Class group of a 3-dimensional hypersurface singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

For $f(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}[z,w]$ a square-free polynomial, consider an affine threefold
$$
X = V(xy + f(z,w)) \subset \mathbb{A}^4.
$$
By computing derivatives one sees that the singularities of $X$ are precisely $(0,0,z,w)$ where $(z,w)$ is a singular point of the plane curve $f(z,w) = 0$. Since $f(z,w)$ is assumed to be square-free, singularities of $X$ are isolated.

The question is: what is the reference and/or a computation for the Class group $Cl(X)$?

UPDATE: These singularities are typicically non-factorial, that is $Cl(X)$ may be strictly bigger than $Pic(X)$. After seeing Jason Starr's comment, I realized that I am more interested in the quotient $Cl(X) / Pic(X)$ rather than $Cl(X)$ itself.

A particular case of the situation above is when $f(z,w)$ is quasi-homogeneous, so that $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is a graded ring, and $Pic(X) = 0$ but $Cl(X)$ does not have to be zero.

Comment: If the codimension of the singular set is $4$ (rather than $3$, as in your case), the standard reference is SGA 2, specifically Grothendieck's proof of the Samuel Conjecture.  However, for codimension $3$, the (Weil divisor) class group can be larger than the Picard group, e.g., this happens if $f(z,w)$ equals $zw$.